# Dynamic native Sql queries for pagination in Spring Data

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I want to get the whole `WHERE`clause as a REST parameter and supply it to PagingAndSortingRepository. Is it possible in Spring? I know I can do this with native sql but I also want to use the paging capabilities of spring. I think QueryDsl won't work for me because the where clause is simply limitless and I have to parse all the parameters in that case.

Ex request:

```
localhost:8080/users?page=0&size=5&where=(firstname+eq+john+and+lastname+neq+terry)or(email+eq+john@gmail.com)
```

I expect it to be sth like:

```
interface UserDAO extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer> {   

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM User ?2", 
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM User ?2", 
        nativeQuery = true)
List<User> getUserList(Pageable pageable, String filter);  
}
```

In a nutshell, I need something to change the `filter` parameter in the above code with the requested `WHERE` clause. Any kind of ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: I should be able to do this by looking at this reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

But I'm still getting "InvalidJpaQueryMethodException:Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination in"

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the count query too, as Example 50. shows. From the docs:

> Note, that we currently don’t support execution of dynamic sorting for native queries as we’d have to manipulate the actual query declared and we cannot do this reliably for native SQL. **You can however use native queries for pagination by specifying the count query yourself**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Actually i did that but didn't work either. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Okay, I get it now, but that won't work repositories. You need to build the whole query yourself.

Comment: Well then, I guess I need to implement it by myself. But anyways, I couldn't make the pageable native query work. So if someone does that, it's still quite good information.